# Remove last symbol in row

Tags: python

My code is:

```
n = 3
for i in range(1, n+1):
    for j in range(1, n+1):
        print(j*i, end='*')
    print(end='\b\n')
```

Result of this code is:

```
1*2*3*
2*4*6*
3*6*9*
```

But I need expected result like this (without aesthetics in end of rows):

```
1*2*3
2*4*6
3*6*9
```

Comment: @Guy the behaviour of printing a ``\b`` character is terminal-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(1, n+1):
    for j in range(1, n+1):
        if(j*i == n*n):
             print(j*i)
        else:
             print(j*i, end='*')
        
    print(end='\b\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `'*'.join()` instead of the `end` parameter in `print()`

```
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    print('*'.join(f'{j * i}' for j in range(1, n + 1)), end='\n')
```

Output

```
1*2*3
2*4*6
3*6*9
```

Comment: @RajeshKanna, please read [Why shouldn't I assume I know who downvoted my post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388686/why-shouldnt-i-assume-i-know-who-downvoted-my-post)

Comment: My apologies to @Guy . And thanks for the link. I have to work on myself more on this. I am new here and learning

Answer (score -1):

Just check if you're not at the last value in the range. If you aren't print '*' if you are don't do anything. View the below code for clarification.

```py
n = 3
for i in range(1, n+1):
    for j in range(1, n+1):
        print(j*i, end='')
        if j != n:
           print('*', end='')
    print(end='\b\n')
```

Answer (score -1):

Using list comprehension we create a list to print in one line and then you can use '*' to expand the list. Then we use 'sep' (separator) param of print function to join them

```
n = 3
for i in range(1, n+1):
    print(*[j*i for j in range(1, n+1)], sep='*', end="\n")
```